# Execute some Javascript onChange using options?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, html-select, onchange

I've been lurking a bit and couldn't find the answer. Basically I have a bunch of buttons that I want to turn into a drop down menu and have the code be executed `onChange`. But, I'm new to javascript and I am having a hard time figuring out how this would work. I somewhat got it to work, but I couldn't get it to work with more than one option.  Here's what I have:

```
<button class="lightbutton" onclick="lightswitch(1,true);lightswitch(2,true);lightswitch(3,true);">
All lights on</button> 
<button class="lightbutton" onclick="lightswitch(1,false);lightswitch(2,false);lightswitch(3,false);">
All lights off</button>
```

I got the lights to turn on by doing this:

```
<form name="functions">
<select name="jumpmenu" onChange="lightswitch(1,true);lightswitch(2,true);lightswitch(3,true);">
<option>LightFunctions</option>
<option value="*";>Light 1 On</option>
<option value="*";>Light 1 Off</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Now, I see why it works -- it's just telling it that whenever it changes to turn on all the lights. But how do I change the "onChange" to make it so it gets whichever option I have chosen?

I think I'm missing some JS but unsure.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: What effect does the 'light 1 On' option have as opposed to the 'light 1 off'? What changes?

Comment: So basically what I'm doing is I have a Philips hue Light setup and the light 1 off, theoretically, would turn the light off and then on would turn it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have that select element control just the first lightswitch you can do this:

```
<select name="jumpmenu" onChange="lightswitch(1,this.value==='on');">
<option value="on";>Light 1 On</option>
<option value="off";>Light 1 Off</option>
</select>
```

That is, instead of hardcoding `true` as the second parameter to `lightswitch()` test the current value of the select element. (Note that I've changed the value attributes to something more meaningful. The expression `this.value==='on'` will evaluate to either `true` or `false`.)

Within the select's `onChange` attribute `this` will refer to the select element itself.

EDIT: To have the same select control multiple parameters you can add some `data-` attributes to the option elements to store as many extra parameters per option as needed (in this case I think you only need one extra). And I'd move the logic out of the inline attribute:

```
<select name="jumpmenu" onChange="jumpChange(this);">
  <option value="">LightFunctions</option>
  <option data-switchNo="1" value="on";>Light 1 On</option>
  <option data-switchNo="1" value="off";>Light 1 Off</option>
  <option data-switchNo="2" value="on";>Light 2 On</option>
  <option data-switchNo="2" value="off";>Light 2 Off</option>
  <option data-switchNo="3" value="on";>Light 3 On</option>
  <option data-switchNo="3" value="off";>Light 3 Off</option>
</select>

function jumpChange(sel) {
   if (sel.value === "") return; // do nothing if user selected first option

   var whichLight = +sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-switchNo");
   lightswitch(whichLight, sel.value==='on');

   sel.value = ""; // reset select to display the "Light Functions" option
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N7b8j/2/

Within the `jumpChange(sel)` function that I added the parameter `sel` will be the select element (set as `this` from the `onChange` attribute). The "magic" happens on this line:

```
var whichLight = +sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-switchNo");
```

To explain that line: `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex]` gets a reference to the currently selected option, and `.getAttribute("data-switchNo")` gets that option's `data-` attribute. The `+` converts the attribute from a string to a number.

Comment: You rock! Is there also a way to make it so this same drop down would control multiple? like "lightswitch(* then some type of variable? I am going to try to have a dropdown to change colors, then one to turn them off and on, and a third to change to select "scenes"  Actually, 1,2 would do it, eh?

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer with a fancier function. Try out my demo. You should be able to extrapolate from there to do the rest of your requirements.

Comment: You have been a lot of help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: One last question. Is there a way to make the first option just a "null" option? It turns the light off when the light is on and I select it.

Comment: Thanks again, nnnnnn, if you get some time maybe you can help me figure out why this is not working either. http://jsfiddle.net/5yaT2/ I have been working for like 8 hours banging my head against my desk!